# Python, requests, error = http.client.BadStatusLine: <ServerStats>

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Trying to get data from a URL, But having trouble with the request. I assume its something to do with the formatting ( there is none ) of the page or data?

I am using Python 3.6.5, requests 2.20.0

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://37.187.88.24:7141/')
print (r)
```

It gives me this error and showing the first line of the page

```
File " ..  \Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_statusraise BadStatusLine(line)http.client.BadStatusLine: <ServerStats>
```

Comment: Try updating requests, urllib3. 

pip install urllib3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response from that server simply does not follow the HTTP protocol. It responds with the content directly without a status line (usually a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`). You can see this with a utility like `curl`:

```
# curl -v http://37.187.88.24:7141/
*   Trying 37.187.88.24...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 37.187.88.24 (37.187.88.24) port 7141 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 37.187.88.24:7141
> User-Agent: curl/7.56.1
> Accept: */*
>
<ServerStats>
<Name>TP_Map_Test</Name>
<ModuleName>Napoleonic Wars</ModuleName>
...(snipped)
```

If you own that web server, fix your web app to give a valid response. If you don't, you can use `telnetlib` to communicate with the server via the underlying telnet protocol instead:

```
from telnetlib import Telnet
t = Telnet('37.187.88.24', 7141)
t.write(b'GET / HTTP/1.0\n')
print(t.read_all())
```

This outputs:

```
b'<ServerStats>\n<Name>TP_Map_Test</Name>\n<ModuleName>Napoleonic Wars</ModuleName>\n<MultiplayerVersionNo>1157</MultiplayerVersionNo>\n<ModuleVersionNo>1210</ModuleVersionNo>\n<MapID>162</MapID>\n<MapName>custom map 1</MapName>\n<MapTypeID>4</MapTypeID>\n<MapTypeName>Deathmatch</MapTypeName>\n<NumberOfActivePlayers>0</NumberOfActivePlayers>\n<MaxNumberOfPlayers>4</MaxNumberOfPlayers>\n<HasPassword>Yes</HasPassword>\n<IsDedicated>Yes</IsDedicated>\n<HasSteamAntiCheat>No</HasSteamAntiCheat>\n<ModuleSetting0>6</ModuleSetting0>\n<ModuleSetting1>8</ModuleSetting1>\n<ModuleSetting2>0</ModuleSetting2>\n<ModuleSetting3>0</ModuleSetting3>\n<ModuleSetting4>1</ModuleSetting4>\n<ModuleSetting5>1</ModuleSetting5>\n<ModuleSetting6>100</ModuleSetting6>\n<ModuleSetting7>0</ModuleSetting7>\n<ModuleSetting8>0</ModuleSetting8>\n<ModuleSetting9>1</ModuleSetting9>\n<ModuleSetting10>2</ModuleSetting10>\n<ModuleSetting11>120</ModuleSetting11>\n<ModuleSetting12>300</ModuleSetting12>\n<ModuleSetting13>5</ModuleSetting13>\n</ServerStats>'
```